# Creating a VisualBrush without ever displaying the Visual it represents

Tags: c#, wpf, image, canvas, visualbrush

Using the code below, I am attempting to fill a `Canvas` with UIElements and save it as a tif `Image`. However, my `Image` is always blank. It is because the `Canvas` is never displayed on the screen and some sort of initialization and drawing never took place? How can I make this work?

The `Canvas` creation would go something like this:

```
Canvas theCanvas = new Canvas();
theCanvas.Width = 2740;
theCanvas.Height = 2280;

...

Button button = new Button();
button.Content = "Push Me.";
button.Height = 50;
button.Width = 200;
Canvas.SetTop(button, 200);
Canvas.SetLeft(button, 300);
theCanvas.Children.Add(button);
```

To create the `Image` and save it:

```
using (System.IO.FileStream fs = 
           new System.IO.FileStream(path, System.IO.FileMode.Create))
{
    RenderTargetBitmap renderBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(
        (int)inWidth,
        (int)inHeight, 1 / 300, 1 / 300, 
        PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

    DrawingVisual visual = new DrawingVisual();
    using (DrawingContext context = visual.RenderOpen())
    {
        VisualBrush brush = new VisualBrush(inCanvas);
        context.DrawRectangle(
            brush,
            null,
            new Rect(new Point(), new Size(inWidth, inHeight)));
    }                

    renderBitmap.Render(visual);

    BitmapEncoder encoder = new TiffBitmapEncoder();
    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderBitmap));
    encoder.Save(fs);
    fs.Close();
}
```

Comment: I had the same problem.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877115/create-wpf-element-offscreen-and-render-to-bitmap

Comment: Well, may be a diff problem (I was doing something wrong) but the code is all there...

Comment: yeah this helped.  I was missing the Measure and Arrange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See first comment on my original post.

Answer (score 0):

In this case control is never rendered on the screen. I just added the canvas to a grid and on a button click I called the save command. And it worked.

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    theCanvas.Width = 2740;
    theCanvas.Height = 2280; 

    Button button = new Button();
    button.Content = "Push Me.";
    button.Height = 50;
    button.Width = 200;
    Canvas.SetTop(button, 200);
    Canvas.SetLeft(button, 300);
    theCanvas.Children.Add(button);
    mainGri.Children.Add(theCanvas);

    }

    private void mainGri_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {



    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        String path = @"c:\\a.jpg";
        using (System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(path, System.IO.FileMode.Create))
        {
            int inWidth = 300;
            int inHeight = 400;
            RenderTargetBitmap renderBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)inWidth,
                                                              (int)inHeight, 1 / 300, 1 / 300, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

            DrawingVisual visual = new DrawingVisual();
            using (DrawingContext context = visual.RenderOpen())
            {
                VisualBrush brush = new VisualBrush(theCanvas);
                context.DrawRectangle(brush,
                                      null,
                                      new Rect(new Point(), new Size(inWidth, inHeight)));
            }

            renderBitmap.Render(visual);

            BitmapEncoder encoder = new TiffBitmapEncoder();
            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderBitmap));
            encoder.Save(fs);
            fs.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: My goal is to not have to display the canvas.