# Convert WPF Path to Bitmap File

Tags: wpf, path, bitmap, render, resourcedictionary

I want to be able to load a WPF Resource Dictionary of Paths and output them one by one to files (jpg, bmp, it doesn't matter).  This will be in a class library that will be accessed by an MVC application to render to a http stream, so I'm doing this purely within code (no XAML pages).

I've been able to load the dictionary and iterate through the paths, but when I save the images to disk, they are blank.  I know I'm missing something trivial, like applying the path to a piece of geometry, or adding it into some containing rectangle or something, but my WPF experience is somewhat limited.

I'm using the following code:

I have a WPF Resource Dictionary containing several paths, such as the following:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Path x:Key="Path1" Data="M 100,200 C 100,25 400,350 400,175 H 280" Fill="White" Margin="10,10,10,10" Stretch="Fill"/>
  <Path x:Key="Path2" Data="M 10,50 L 200,70" Fill="White" Margin="10,10,10,10" Stretch="Fill"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And the class to read and output the files:

```
public class XamlRenderer
{
    public void RenderToDisk()
    {
        ResourceDictionary resource = null;

        Thread t = new Thread(delegate()
        {
            var s = new FileStream(@"C:\Temp\myfile.xaml", FileMode.Open);
            resource = (ResourceDictionary)XamlReader.Load(s);
            s.Close();

            foreach (var item in resource)
            {
                var resourceItem = (DictionaryEntry)item;
                var path = (System.Windows.Shapes.Path)resourceItem.Value;

                var panel = new StackPanel();

                var greenBrush = new SolidColorBrush {Color = Colors.Green};

                path.Stroke = Brushes.Blue;
                path.StrokeThickness = 2;
                path.Fill = greenBrush;

                panel.Children.Add(path);

                panel.UpdateLayout();

                string filepath = @"C:\Temp\Images\" + resourceItem.Key + ".jpg";

                SaveImage(panel, 64, 64, filepath);
            }
        });

        t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        t.Start();
    }

    public void SaveImage(Visual visual, int width, int height, string filePath)
    {
        var bitmap =
            new RenderTargetBitmap(width, height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        bitmap.Render(visual);

        var image = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        image.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmap));
        using (Stream fs = File.Create(filePath))
        {
            image.Save(fs);
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After much googling, and trial and error, I seem to have arrived at a solution.  This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877115/create-wpf-element-offscreen-and-render-to-bitmap) pointed me in the right direction.
There were a few issues:

- I was now setting the size of the path and the container
- The stack panel container has some nuances that were causing issues, so I replaced it with a canvas
- Most importantly, `Measure()` and `Arrange()` need to be called on the container element.  The `UpdateLayout()` call is not needed.

Once these issues were fixed, the images rendered to disk (although there's an aspect ratio problem I have yet to fix).

Here is the updated code:

```
    public void RenderToDisk()
    {
        ResourceDictionary resource = null;

        Thread t = new Thread(delegate()
        {
            var s = new FileStream(@"C:\Temp\myfile.xaml", FileMode.Open);
            resource = (ResourceDictionary)XamlReader.Load(s);
            s.Close();

            foreach (var item in resource)
            {
                var resourceItem = (DictionaryEntry)item;
                var path = (System.Windows.Shapes.Path)resourceItem.Value;

                path.Margin = new Thickness(10);
                path.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                path.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
                path.Width = 48;
                path.Height = 48;
                path.Stroke = Brushes.White;
                path.Fill = Brushes.Black;

                var canvas = new Canvas();
                canvas.Width = 64;
                canvas.Height = 64;
                canvas.Margin = new Thickness(0);
                canvas.Background = Brushes.Transparent;

                canvas.Children.Add(path);

                canvas.Measure(new Size(canvas.Width, canvas.Height));
                canvas.Arrange(new Rect(new Size(canvas.Width, canvas.Height)));

                string filepath = @"C:\Temp\Images\" + resourceItem.Key + ".png";

                SaveImage(canvas, (int)canvas.Width, (int)canvas.Height, filepath);
            }
        });

        t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        t.Start();
    }
```